# Html Content parse to json model

Tags: javascript, c#, json, mvc

Можно ли как-то с помощю js распарсить данные со страницы в json формат автоматически?
Есть например, страница со следующими полями

```
<form id="form1">
    <input id="Title" type="text" value="Testttttt"/>
    <textarea id ="Content">Contenttttttt</textarea>
    <input id="tbSave" type="button" value="Сохранить"/>
</form>
```

И есть модель

```
[JsonObject]
public class TestModel
{
    [JsonProperty("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Контроллер

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult tbSave(Models.Test.TestModel model)
{
    return new JsonResult();
}
```

И скрипт

```
$('#tbSave').click(function () {
    var title = $("#Title").val();
    var content = $("#Content").val();
    //var jsonData = $(this).serialize();
    var jsonData = {
        Title: title,
        Content: content
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Test/tbSave',
        data: jsonData,
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        complete: function () {

        },
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
});
```

В данном примере все работает, данные приходят в контроллер. Но тут надо формировать json модель в ручную (т.е. парсить html контент вот так var title = $("#Title").val();).
Можно ли как-то обойтись без парса вручную, чтоб json модель парсилась по идентификаторам полей (ну вызвать что-то типа var jsonData = $(this).parse() и чтоб весь контент сам распарсился)?

P.S. Пробовал так (var jsonData = $("#form1").serialize();), не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При наличие атрибута "name" у полей:

```
var data = $("#form").serialize();
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Есть ещё вопросик. Я использую вот такую конструкцию (@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Content)), для создания полей, теперь прийдется всегода писать вот так @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Content, new { @name = "Content" }) (т.е. всегда указывать name) или всё же можно как-то селиализовавать по id?

Comment: @Voucik а что вам мешает писать вот так: `<textarea name="Content">@Model.Content</textarea>`?

Comment: Так мне ничего не мешает писать, просто удобнее @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Content) ибо тут идёт привязка к модели и мне сразу подсветится, если я напишу не правильно, да и подсказки выскакивают (то есть список полей). Да и весь код сам генерируется (ну там проверочки всякие и т.д. в зависимости от атрибутов модели), то есть мне меньше писать. В общем это только вопрос удобства.

Comment: name стандартный идентификатор для полей форм